# How would you make a Diving Board?

Tags: physics

I would like to bend an object by hitting it with another object but I don't want the first object to just fling about after getting hit. I would like to know how to "pin" and object, say a long board, like a diving board. That's actually a perfect example, a Diving Board, how would you make a Diving Board?! Thanks! :)